# JHipster session issue on Kubernetes

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

We are deploying Jhipster Apps on Kubernetes - Registry in a microservices setup and a monolithic application (all generated using 6.7.1 with KeyCloak). And we believe this issue exists with 6.10.5 too )When we increase the pod count of either Registry or Mono to two, these applications start behaving weirdly and we start seeing the error

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Similar to https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/10642

We tried everything stated above but we suspect :

1. Since UI uses cookie , we assume it to be stateful and session replication is not happening when deployed on Kubernetes. Is there a Jhipster configuration that we need to set to start session replication - since it already uses HazelCast?
2. Our KeyCloak is deployed in the same cluster and same namespace using Official KeyCloak HelmCharts since jhipster kubernetes does not provide them.